# Mutable rlist when first item holds a mutable pair (homework)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def mutable_pair(x,y):
    def get_item(index):
        if index == 0:
            return x
        return y
    def set_item(index , val):
        nonlocal x,y
        if  index == 0:
            x = val
        else:    
            y = val    

def make_dict():    
    contents = None
    def make_rlist(first,rest):
        return (first,rest)

    def dispatch(message,key,value):
        nonlocal contents
        if message == 'push_first':
            contents = make_rlist(mutable_pair(key, value), contents)
z = make_dict()
z('push_first')(2,4)
```

i have this problem that when im  trying to run this code i get the next error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Michael\workspace\HomeWork1\src\tests.py", line 35, in <module>
z('push_first')(2,4)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable:
```

an explenation to where im wrong would be helpfull

Comment: `make_dict()` returns `None`. You're assigning that to `z`, and trying to call it: `z('push_first')`. As the error message says, `None is not callable`. What do you expect `z('push_first')(2,4)` to do, anyway?

Comment: In gerneral we are need to make a mutable list while not using any build in python type, i belive its called nested pairs of some sort

Comment: we need to create this - http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa11/61a-python/content/section_notes/week5/notes05_sol.pdf - in general but useig a dispatch dictionary

Comment: Maybe `mutable_pair` and `make_dict` should be classes?

Comment: It cant be for this exercise unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable:

`make_dict` returns `None`, so `z` is `None` and `z('push_first')` won't work.

Comment: Why does make_dict returns None?

Comment: It doesn't return anything. Python functions will return `None` by default in this case.